# FactoryBot: Check if trait has been passed in

Tags: factory-bot

I am trying to put a conditional piece of logic into a factory that will only run if a specific trait has been passed in as an argument. I am inside the `to_create` block so have access to the instance and the evaluator. Do either of them have a method that returns which traits, if any, have been passed in?

Comment: Also interested in this! I have 4 traits and the model can be any one of those 4 choices. I want to randomly instantiate one of those four traits IFF those fields or a specific trait was not provided by the caller. Not sure how to accomplish this.